# What does *--end() mean in C++?

Tags: c++, std-filesystem

Looking at [this cppreference.com page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename) for `std::filesystem::path::filename`, the method's description is literaly just "equivalent to `relative_path().empty() ? path() : *--end()`". I've never seen that syntax "*--end()". I can figure out what it does from the context, but what does it mean exactly? And could it be used in a different context to extract, say, a substring?

Comment: `end()` returns an iterator that is is one past the last element. `--` makes the iterator point to the one before it, the last element. `*` gets the element referred to by the iterator.

Comment: Essentially, it would mean same as `back()` if `path` had that member like containers do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's look at [`std::filesystem::path::begin()/end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/begin). This allows you to iterate through a path one directory at a time, so for `/user/kenyn/foo.bar` with this code:

```
fs::path p = "/user/kenyn/foo.bar";
for(auto &e : p)
    std::cout << e << '\n';
```

We would see:

```
user
kenyn
foo.bar
```

So, what is `*(--(p.end()))`? I've added extra brackets so we can see we get an iterator pointing to one past the last element with `p.end()`, move back one with the `--` to get a reference to `foo.bar`, then dereference the iterator with `*` to give us a pointer to the final path element `"foo.bar"`.

The complete expression, then:

```
relative_path().empty() ? path() : *--end()
```

Says if there is no relative path (ie, just a file name or nothing at all), return the whole thing, else if there is a relative path, return the last element of the list of paths, which will be the file name.